# Scale inside Scale Conversion

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I tracked a mouse position inside a website, and this website has a height bigger than the visable area, so you can scroll. I captured the mouse y position based on the current view area (0 to 100), and also captured the amount of scroll that you did (0%, 10%, 20%, ..., 100%).

**How can I know (not precisely) the correct position of your mouse position, given: `CurrentMouseYOnView` and `CurrentAmountOfScroll`?**

It's not precisely, because if you scrolled 12%, I will calculate based on 10%.

Follow the image to explain a little better:

[Image of Problem Visual Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwPlY.png)

Comment: The question looks more like it belongs on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead of MSE. Unless more context is provided, I am voting to close the question as off-topic (and unrelated to Mathematics).

Comment: @an4s I think it's more about how to approach in a mathemical view, while the context (browser, mouse position) are just context, which could be any kind of natural information.

Comment: "How can I know (not precisely) the correct position of your mouse..." seems redundant when you have "already captured the mouse y position..." (I assume you care only about the $y$-position and not the $x$). What exactly do you need to calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Map the $0\%$ scroll to when the view window and full page have top edge aligned, and $100\%$ to when the bottom of the view window is aligned to the bottom of the full page.

Let the full length be $Y$ and the window height be $H$

Considering the top edge of the window as the reference, we are creating a linear scale of scrolling as

$(0, Y-H) \rightarrow(0, 100)$

Hence an $x\%$ scroll would correspond to the top edge being at

$$y_{top} =\frac{x(Y-H)}{100}$$

This is in the fixed reference of the full page

Now, within the page, you know the location of the mouse pointer as $y_{point}$

Hence, the position of the pointer would be

$$y_{true} = y_{top} + y_{point} = y_{point} + \frac{x(Y-H)}{100}$$